# Open VLC browse file window in Python

Tags: python, ubuntu, vlc

I am trying to make a program in python to open a VLC "Browsing File window" on Ubuntu

```
global process
import io,sys,os
import subprocess

myprocess = subprocess.call(['vlc','/home/tansen'])
```

but the code above just opens the 'VLC Player' not the file opening window
Can you please guide me on how to get the required result
I am adding the vlc filing opening image as well[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

according to the [documentation](http://www.videolan.org/doc/vlc-user-guide/en/ch04.html), the correct syntax should be

`vlc -vvv video.mp4`

and the python code that you can use is

`subprocess.POPEN(['vlc', '-vvv', '/path/to/video.mp4'])`

You can also add the `PIPE` to dump the output from vlc as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer>
but i just want to file browsing window, not the actual file.

Comment: ahh.. sorry i thought that you have the file that you want to play

Answer (score 0):

What OS platform?

On Linux: If you run qdbusviewer you'll see the dbus methods available.  I don't see one for showing the file dialog, but there is one for opening a URL:

```
qdbus org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.OpenUri test.mp3
```

So from Python:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["qdbus", "org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc", "/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2", "org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.OpenUri", "file:///home/john/test.mp3"])'
```

Or:

```
import gobject
gobject.threads_init()
from dbus import glib
glib.init_threads()
import dbus
bus = dbus.SessionBus()
obj = bus.get_object("org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc", "/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2")
iface = dbus.Interface(obj, "org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player")
iface.OpenUri("file:///home/john/test.mp3")
```

On Windows: Try COM?